# How to import API route in NextJS for getStaticProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I am using NextJS's `getStaticProps` to fetch some data from an external API. Reading the data fetching documentation on [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) I came across this particular note:

> Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in your
> application. Instead, directly import the API route and call its
> function yourself. You may need to slightly refactor your code for
> this approach.

Right now I am calling `getStaticProps` directly from a page component called `Index` as follows:

```
export default function Index({ data }) {
  return <div>{data}</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data");
  const data = await response.json();
  return { props: { data } };
}
```

As per the above documentation, this should not be done. How can I restructure my code to fetch data correctly? What does it mean to "import the API route and call its function yourself?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the *Note* is related to **internal api path**

> You should not use fetch() to call an API route in **your application**

I suppose is related to every path that you define in `/pages/api/*`. Instead of `fetch` you can simply refactor your code and import data.

So, the code below is correct, don't need any refactoring

```js
export default function Index({ data }) {
  return <div>{data}</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data");
  const data = await response.json();
  return { props: { data } };
}
```